# Loading details from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I was using this:

```
SELECT res.*, rac.*, u.*, t.*, c.*
FROM Results res
INNER JOIN Races rac USING (RaceID)
INNER JOIN Users u USING (UserID)
INNER JOIN Teams t USING (TeamID)
INNER JOIN Cars c USING (CarID)
WHERE res.SeasonNumber = '$SeasonNumber' AND res.LeagueID = '$LeagueID' AND Position = '1' AND ResultConfirmed = '1'
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

Which works fine, but I've since realised I need to have CarID added in to Results table, but when I add it in, it gives me the error that the field is ambiguous. What I'd like to do is get the Car name from Cars table where CarID joins Cars and Results. When I try to do this though:

```
SELECT res.*, rac.*, u.*, t.*, c.*
FROM Results res
INNER JOIN Races rac USING (RaceID)
INNER JOIN Users u USING (UserID)
INNER JOIN Teams t USING (TeamID)
INNER JOIN Cars c USING (res.CarID)
WHERE res.SeasonNumber = '$SeasonNumber' AND res.LeagueID = '$LeagueID' AND Position = '1' AND ResultConfirmed = '1'
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.CarID) WHERE res.SeasonNumber = '1' AND res.LeagueID = '1' AND
>   Position = '1' ' at line 6

Comment: Try SELECT res.*, rac.*, u.*, t.*, `c.CarID` FROM Results res

Comment: I suspect the reason that `res.CarID` is a syntax error is because `USING` means comparing columns of the same name, so you can't specify any column with it's table reference. The `CarID` is perhaps ambiguous, due to it possibly existing in another table in the `JOIN` list. Thus, use an explicit `ON rac.CarID = res.CarID` for your `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `USING` clause with `ON()`,in `USING()` clause i guess you add the columns name that are same in other table you are joining but you placed the join in last and using alias `res` mysql won't allow this

```
INNER JOIN Cars c ON(res.CarID =c.CarID)
```

If you need to use `USING()` clause you need to adjust the join placements like

```
SELECT res.*, rac.*, u.*, t.*, c.*
FROM 
Cars c
INNER JOIN Results res USING (CarID)
INNER JOIN Races rac USING (RaceID)
INNER JOIN Users u USING (UserID)
INNER JOIN Teams t USING (TeamID)
WHERE res.SeasonNumber = '$SeasonNumber' AND res.LeagueID = '$LeagueID' AND Position = '1' AND ResultConfirmed = '1'
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

But `ON()` clause is more readable form

Comment: Thanks for this. I did try `INNER JOIN Cars c ON (res.CarID)` but it duplicated the results.

Comment: @BN83 yes it will give you if there is a one-to-many relation i guess you need a single car foreach of your row ? if your row is fully duplicated you can use `SELECT DISTINCT ...`